# How react native listView to get numbering to display?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display following things included numbering (will come from API) using listView but API haven't the numbering:

1. John
2. Peter
3. Mary
4. May
5. Charlie

---

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        {name: "John"},
        {name: "Peter"},
        {name: "Mary"},
        {name: "May"},
        {name: "Charlie"}
      ])
    };   }

render() {
    return (
       <View>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>}
            />
        </View>    );   }
```

---

I can only display items without numbering. Who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rowID to get the current index of the item, and increment from there:

```
renderRow (rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
  rowID++
  return <Text>{rowID}. {rowData.name}</Text>
}
```

I've set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/hxlAqw).

https://rnplay.org/apps/hxlAqw

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly I want